# C# List issue, inclusive list

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an issue and I can't seem to resolve it basically I have two list of int one which may or not include the other, and I need to draw an if condition just to check among the incoming list which set of the int it is coming from and make a decision so I have used

so I have a boolean function

```
public bool firstiterate()
{
  var listint= new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
  var incoming= returned.Select(s=s.ref);

  if(incoming.All(listint.Contains)
  {
  //dosomething
  }
}
```

and the second function as:

```
public bool seconditerate()
{
  var listint= new List<int>(){1,2,3,4};
  var incoming= returned.Select(s=s.ref);

  if(incoming.Any(listint.Contains) && !incoming.All(listint.Contains)
  {
  //dosomething
  }
}
```

but all my booleans are returning null on all cases even though either one should return something, What am I doing wrong. any help would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: How could any of those ever work? `incomingint` is not part of the conditions.

Comment: sorry was a typo from my side, corrected it now.Thans

Answer (score 1):

This fails to reproduce. Turn it into a small but complete program. Currently the error is not where you think it is.

My code:

```
        var returned = new List<int> { 4, 5, 8 };

        var listint = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var incoming = returned.Select(s => s);       //

        if (incoming.All(listint.Contains))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("if1");
        }

        if (incoming.Any(listint.Contains) && !incoming.All(listint.Contains))
        {
            //dosomething
            Console.WriteLine("if2");
        }
```

This prints "if2"

Comment: thanks for the answer but this didn't work as expected, instead of printing "if2" as you said on your post, it always print "if1" not sure the reason but I am running out of possibilities.

Comment: This code, with this data, should print "if2". Double-check your findings.

Comment: Not just theoretically - drop this code in a new, clean, Console project. Check that it works and start looking for the differences. Nobody will be able to help you further based on what you posted here.

Comment: Hi all, just as a head up I have resolved to using two different LINQ Query to get the result and it seems to be working in my case not sure as to why. So I have used 'code' Var incomingAll=returned.Select(s => s).All(listint.Contains); and 'code' var incomingAny=returned.Select(s => s).Any(listint.Contains)